# Как добавить фильтрацию в WordPress в админке для записей?

Tags: wordpress

Создал пользовательский тип записи в Wp , как добавить сюда фильтрацию по категориям ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Добавить сам селект ты можешь так:

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'my_restrict_manage_posts', 10 );
function my_restrict_manage_posts( $post_type ) {
    if( 'my-custom-post' !== $post_type ) ) {
      return;
    }
    //тут выводишь свой селект
}
```

Затем нужно повлиять на выбор постов:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts, 10 );
function my_pre_get_posts( $admin_query ) {

    global $pagenow;

    if ( is_admin()
         && $admin_query->is_main_query()
         && 'my-custom-post' === $_GET['post_type']
         && 'edit.php' === $pagenow
    ) {

        if ( ! empty( $_GET['your-select-option'] ) ) {

            $admin_query->set(
                'tax_query',
                [
                    [
                        'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy',
                        'field'    => 'id',
                        'terms'    => (int)$_GET['your-select-option']

                    ]
                ]
            );

        }
    }
}
```